# How to fill JSTL var with an ArrayList and iterate it to populate a select without using Servlet

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jstl, el, usebean

I'm trying to get some `specialities` from a function called `getAllSpecialities()` (which's inside of `MedicBean`) and *store* them in a JSTL/EL var called `specialitiesList`. This function returns an `ArrayList` of `Strings` and it works fine, it returns all the specialities, the problem comes in the jsp. I don't know why, the var `specialitiesList` is not being filled, it's just `null`, so I can't iterate over it to populate the `select`.

This is what I've been trying to do:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select an speciality</option>
    <jsp:useBean id="medicAux" class="Model.MedicBean"/>
    <c:set var="specialitiesList" value="${medicAux.allSpecialities}"/>
    <c:forEach items="${specialitiesList}" var="speciality">
        <option value="${speciality}">${speciality}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This is the `getAllSpecialities()` method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllSpecialities(){

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    ArrayList<String> specialities = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        conn = Conexion.conectar();

        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT SPECIALITY FROM MEDICO";  
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            specialities.add(rs.getString("speciality"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MedicoBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("error: "+ex.getMessage());
    }

    Conexion.desconectar(conn);

    return specialities;
}`
```

What am I doing wrong? If you need some extra info, just ask for it. Thanks!

Comment: How you fill `specialities` in you bean? Which you get when invoke `getAllSpecialities()`?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. `getAllSpecialities()` returns an `ArrayList` of `Strings`.

Comment: Please add code of  `getAllSpecialities()` method.

Comment: I think that it has nothing to do with the problem. As I said, I've test that method and it returns the `ArrayList` with the specialities. It works fine. Do you still need to see it?

Comment: Yes and add code where you instaintiate variable that retrun from `getAllSpecialities()`

Comment: @AlexanderPodkutin done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105487/discussion-between-alexander-podkutin-and-drumnbass).